# Updating advice in function

Tags: advice

I've noticed that if function `f` is used to advise function `g` through `advice-add`, and function `f` is then redefined, function `g`'s advice is not updated.

After digging into `advice-add` a bit, it is clear that `advice-add` uses `add-function` behind the scenes, which means that it extracts the value in the function cell of `f` and uses it to advise `g`. Therefore, when `f` is redefined, `g` is not affected.

I'm wondering why such a design decision was made. Is there a good reason that we *shouldn't* or *couldn't* allow updating `f` to update `g`'s advice as well?

Comment: I happily can redefine a function `f` and get the effect on adviced `g` with `GNU Emacs 24.4.1`. I have `(defun g ()"g")`, `(defun f  (org-fun &rest args) (concat "f" (apply org-fun args)))` and `(advice-add 'g :around #'f)`. Whenever I change `f` the effect is visible if I call `(g)`.

Comment: I do not understand exactly what you mean.  Please give some example code/session to show what you did, what you got, and what you wanted to get instead.

Comment: Actually, I think I was just confused after screwing around with advices. @theldoria is correct.